# Multiline Editing in VIM (Using Marks)

Tags: vim, multiline, editing

Does anyone know of a pre-existing technique to edit multiple lines in VIM using Marks or something similar?  I use Shift+I / Shift+A when visually selecting columns to insert before and after, it would be nice to something similar with "uneven" or "Jagged" lines.

Example of "Jagged" Lines:

```
<a href="new/link/"> same link </a>
<a href="new/link/to/another/area/"> next link </a>
<a href="old/link/same/content/"> same size </a>
<a href="interesting/tmp/same/info/"> size same </a>
<a href="to/a/great/place/known/the_same/"> what link </a>
<a href="another/new/link/"> this link </a>
<a href="into/links/"> some link </a>
```

In this example, I'd want to adjust the internal text of the link: "same link", "next link", "same size" etc.

This could easily be done with a regular expression, but would also be nice if it could be done with marks somehow.

Example Workflow:

- Go to begining of each similar sized item to edit
- Mark with '[a-z,A-z] etc.
- `:MarkInsertMode`  # << Something Similar to this, ideally mapped
- Then it works just as Shift+A or Shift+I, editing shows on single line and updates on all lines

Most likely if there are no answers for this one I'll be writing a script to do it, but I'm curious if anything like this is out there so far.

Comment: You might try this plugin [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors). It looks like it should do what you want using multiple visual selections.

Comment: can you explain why you want to use "marks" to do that over `:s/../../`?  `:s` is so straightforward. also you could record a macro to do that too, but I would use `:s` if I were you. or I didn't understand your requirement?

Comment: I currently use the sed expressions to edit my lines, but it's non-ideal, steps you out of the moment to think of a regular expression while editing.

Comment: Thanks FDinoff!  That looks great, I'll check it out, if it's as advertised in those beautiful gifs, this should do the trick!

Comment: @VitaPluvia Tell me how it goes. (But I only recommended it because the gifs looked like what you wanted. I've never used the plugin)

Comment: It's a bit buggy, but this is definitely being added to my normal routine now!  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vim-multiple-cursors plugin](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) was already mentioned in the comments. If the text you're editing is identical, an alternative is my [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321); which provides a new `gc` command that works like built-in `c`, but after leaving insert mode applies the local substitution to all other occurrences.

Comment: This works, but it's still pretty buggy at the moment